# Group by and apply string in one entry to whole group

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply a string to group based off the non null value in the group. An example is:

```
ID    name    surname  prsn_id
 A    john      smith  prsn_01
 A    john      smith      NaN
 A    john      smith      NaN
 A    john      smith      NaN
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane       NaN
 B    mary      jane       NaN
 B    mary      jane       NaN
 B    mary      jane       NaN
 B    mary      jane       NaN
 B    mary      jane       NaN
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis       Nan
 C    Barry   willis       Nan
 C    Barry   willis       Nan
 C    Barry   willis       Nan
```

The output should be:

```
ID    name    surname  prsn_id
 A    john      smith  prsn_01
 A    john      smith  prsn_01
 A    john      smith  prsn_01
 A    john      smith  prsn_01
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03
```

or:

```
ID    name    surname  prsn_id    prsn_id_2
 A    john      smith  prsn_01          NaN
 A    john      smith      NaN      prsn_01
 A    john      smith      NaN      prsn_01
 A    john      smith      NaN      prsn_01
 B    mary      jane   prsn_02          NaN
 B    mary      jane       NaN      prsn_02
 B    mary      jane       NaN      prsn_02
 B    mary      jane       NaN      prsn_02
 B    mary      jane       NaN      prsn_02
 B    mary      jane       NaN      prsn_02
 B    mary      jane       NaN      prsn_02
 C    Barry   willis   prsn_03          NaN
 C    Barry   willis       Nan      prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis       Nan      prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis       Nan      prsn_03
 C    Barry   willis       Nan      prsn_03
```

I have tried:

```
df['prsn_id_2'] = (df
                 .groupby(['ID', 'name', 'surname'])['prsn_id']
                 .fillna(method='ffill'))
```

This may work, however it is taking along time so will not be very practical going forward. I need another solution that is vectorised and relatively quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove `NaN`s rows and then left join with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['prsn_id'])
#if possible duplicates
#df1 = df.dropna(subset=['prsn_id']).drop_duplicates(['ID','name', 'surname'])
df = df.drop('prsn_id', axis=1).merge(df1, on=['ID','name', 'surname'], how='left')
print (df)
   ID   name surname  prsn_id
0   A   john   smith  prsn_01
1   A   john   smith  prsn_01
2   A   john   smith  prsn_01
3   A   john   smith  prsn_01
4   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
5   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
6   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
7   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
8   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
9   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
10  B   mary    jane  prsn_02
11  C  Barry  willis  prsn_03
12  C  Barry  willis  prsn_03
13  C  Barry  willis  prsn_03
14  C  Barry  willis  prsn_03
15  C  Barry  willis  prsn_03
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1)
   ID   name surname  prsn_id
0   A   john   smith  prsn_01
4   B   mary    jane  prsn_02
11  C  Barry  willis  prsn_03
```